Apply CSS based on children
I'm not sure if it possible: I need to apply some CSS border based on elements present inside a parent div.
These parent div are generated dynamically, so, sometimes it has 2 children (ta-1 and ta-2), and sometimes only 1 child (ta-1 or ta-2)
For example (with both):
Here I want that ta-1 has: border radius only on top, and ta-2 border radius only on bottom:
<div class="parent">
    <textarea class="ta-1"></textarea>
    <textarea class="ta-2"></textarea>
</div>

CSS:
.parent .ta-1 { border-top-left-radius: 50%; border-top-right-radius: 50%; }
.parent .ta-2 { border-bottom-left-radius: 50%; border-bottom-right-radius: 50%; }

But if I have only a child, I need to apply border radius to all 4 corners of ta-...
<div class="parent">
    <textarea class="ta-2"></textarea>
</div>

CSS:
.parent .ta-1 { border-top-left-radius: 50%; border-top-right-radius: 50%; border-bottom-left-radius: 50%; border-bottom-right-radius: 50%; }
.parent .ta-2 { border-top-left-radius: 50%; border-top-right-radius: 50%; border-bottom-left-radius: 50%; border-bottom-right-radius: 50%; }

Is there a code that check if there are both children to apply radius only on 2 corner of each ta-..., and check if there is only one ta-... child apply to all 4 corners?

maybe using .parent:has(.ta-1:only-child) for the case where you have only one child

If you're applying borders to the .ta-* elements, then you're not styling the parent based on the children, instead you're styling the children based on the presence or absence of another sibling. Am I missing something, because so far as I can tell this works: simple demo?

You can use :has with :not element of css.


.parent .ta-1 {
  border-top-left-radius: 25%;
  border-top-right-radius: 25%;
}

.parent .ta-2 {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25%;
}

.parent1:has(:not(.t2)) .ta-1 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #F00;
}

.parent2:has(:not(.t1)) .ta-2 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #0F0;
}
<div class="parent">
  <textarea class="ta-1"></textarea>
  <textarea class="ta-2"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="parent1">
  <textarea class="ta-1"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="parent2">
  <textarea class="ta-2"></textarea>
</div>




:has(:not()) can be used from a single selector.


.parent .ta-1 {
  border-top-left-radius: 25%;
  border-top-right-radius: 25%;
}

.parent .ta-2 {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25%;
}

div.parent:not(:has(:nth-last-child(2)))> textarea{
  border-radius: 1em;
  border-color: red;
}
<div class="parent">
  <textarea class="ta-1"></textarea>
  <textarea class="ta-2"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <textarea class="ta-1"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <textarea class="ta-2"></textarea>
</div>



You do not even need class to draw your borders, let draw them only on the first and las-child


.parent> :first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 1em;
  border-top-right-radius: 1em;
}

.parent> :last-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
}

/* demo purpose */
.parent {
  display: grid;
  width: max-content;
  margin:1em;
  padding:1em;
  border:solid;
}
<div class="parent">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea>one in the middle</textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>



